# APEX Office print

Tags: oracle, printing, oracle-apex

I am currently working with the Apex Office Print it would be nice if you could help me with two points.

- I am creating a template with a lot of fields, and around 50% of
  these fields are optional, so they are often only (null) in my
  database. Can I do something so that the fields with no value are not
  shown?
- My second question would be the work with the print function and
  checkboxes. How do I integrate the item APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01  so
  that I only print the content of a selected checkbox ? It is not
  really working in the PL/SQL section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am creating a template with a lot of fields, and around 50% of these fields are optional, so they are often only (null) in my database. Can I do something so that the fields with no value are not shown?

The {tag} will just be removed when it's empty. In case you want to make some blocks disappear you can wrap that in a condition,
for example:

```
{#tags=null} {product_name}: {product_description} {/tags=null} {#tags!=null} {product_name}: {tags} {/tags!=null}
```

or if you have a value:

```
{#checked=="Yes"}☒Yes ☐No{/checked=="Yes"}{#checked!="Yes"} ☐Yes ☒No {/checked!="Yes"}
```

> My second question would be the work with the print function and checkboxes. How do I integrate the item APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 so that I only print the content of a selected checkbox ? It is not really working in the PL/SQL section.

Are you running the AOP Process type plugin or the Dynamic Action plugin?

For example we use it for ourself when selecting invoices and printing them.

We have a checkbox in an IR:

```
apex_item.checkbox2(
  p_idx => 1,
  p_value => id,
  p_attributes => 'class="invoice_id"',
  p_checked_values => :P39_INVOICE_ID_LIST,
  p_checked_values_delimiter => ',') as chk,
```

And then we have a Dynamic Action on change that sets an hidden item (P39_INVOICE_ID_LIST) on the page:

```
var
  //Checkbox that was changed
  $checkBox = $(this.triggeringElement),
  //DOM object for APEX Item that holds list.
  apexItemIDList = apex.item(this.affectedElements.get(0)),
  //Convert comma list into an array or blank array
  //Note: Not sure about the "?" syntax see: http://www.talkapex.com/2009/07/javascript-if-else.html
  ids = apexItemIDList.getValue().length === 0 ? [] : apexItemIDList.getValue().split(','),
  //Index of current ID. If it's not in array, value will be -1
  idIndex = ids.indexOf($checkBox.val())
;
//If box is checked and it doesn't already exist in list
if ($checkBox.is(':checked') && idIndex < 0) {
  ids.push($checkBox.val());
}
//If box is unchecked and it exists in list
else if (!$checkBox.is(':checked') && idIndex >= 0){
  ids.splice(idIndex, 1);
}
//Convert array back to comma delimited list
apexItemIDList.setValue(ids.join(','));
```

In our query in the AOP DA we have:

```
where i.id in (select regexp_substr(:P39_INVOICE_ID_LIST,'[^,]+', 1, level) invoice_id
                 from dual
              connect by regexp_substr(:P39_INVOICE_ID_LIST, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

and we make sure the P39_INVOICE_ID_LIST is set in session state by specifying the Affected Elements of the AOP plugin call.

If you setup an example of what you want to do on apex.oracle.com I'm happy to build you the example there. In AOP 4.0 we will also include an example with checkboxes.

Hope that helps,
Dimitri

Comment: im currently trying to create a good example for you to understand. Thanks dimitri

Comment: Dimitri, just found that !==null doesn't work as expected, but !=null does. Please fix your example above. Would also be great to include that in the docs. Thanks, Peter

Comment: thanks - I changed it. it actually depends on what is being passed. !== null is only supporting that, whereas != null also supports undefinied.